# How do you know you have to use function() {}?

Tags: jquery, lambda, anonymous-function

code 1

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.poem-stanza').addClass('highlight');
});
```

code 2

```
$(document).ready(
    $('.poem-stanza').addClass('highlight');
);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You read the documentation for the method you are calling (the `ready` method in this case) and see what sort of value it expects.

If it expects a function, use your first example.

If it expects a jQuery* object, use your second example (since the return value from the addClass method is a jQuery object).

*I assume you are using jQuery as I think it is the only library that has functions named like that. I could be wrong though, [$ is a stupid name for a function](http://blog.dorward.me.uk/2009/02/19/the-dollar-function-must-die.html).

Comment: I disagree with your "$ is a stupid name for a function." blog entry, but the "comment" link leads to your contact page so I write it here: Where is the first point quoted from, and why is it that way? Your third point counts for every function name not just $. And in jquery, the $ function is not only for selectors, but also a shorthand for document.ready, as you can read here: http://docs.jquery.com/Core/jQuery#callback

Comment: The quote is from the ECMAScript specification. Function names usually give some clue as to what they do - a dollar sign does not. And great - the function is overloaded, thus making it even more obscure.

Answer (score 0):

If the function accepts a function as a parameter, code 2 will not work, because

```
$('.poem-stanza').addClass('highlight');
```

is not a function definition (it's a statement)

To create an object that represents a function, one of the following syntaxes should be used:

```
function myFunc() {
}
```

or

```
var myFunc = function() {
}
```

or

```
var myFunc = new Function("...javascript code...");
```

After one of the definitions above, **myFunc** will hold an object representing a function.

Answer (score 0):

Heh, that's how it is :D

No, seriously, when you have to do something inside ready(); or similar methods, you use an. function. Other methods accept parameters. Docs will provide you with details.

Answer (score 0):

Like the other guys said, you have to look up the documentation to see, what type of parameters the function accepts. However, the important part here is this: If you have a statement, it gets execute when the interpreter come across it. If you define a function and pass it to the ready function, the ready function decides when to execute it. In this particular case, when the document is ready. Another example is setTimeout which expects a function and a number of milliseconds as parameters.

The rule is this: When you want to pass some code to some other function, you have to wrap it in a function. If you use a (unwrapped) statement, it will be executed and the result is passed to the function.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a callback function, you use the function keyword. When you use methods like `ready` and `click`, you don't want the code to run when you set up the event, but when the event happens, so you need a callback function.

Using an anonymous function is just like using a named function that you defined earlier. In an example like this it's easier to follow what's happening:

```
function onReady() {
    $('.poem-stanza').addClass('highlight');
}

$(document).ready(onReady);
```